# Why I cannot clean a table extracted with the read_html property?

Tags: pandas

I am looking forward to extract a table with the `read_html` property.

```
route=pd.read_html(https://whatever.com,flavor='html5lib',thousands='.', decimal=',')
```

I am interested in the first value of the array which brings out a table like this:

```
route[1]:

   Cambio de %    Volumen
0          NaN        NaN
1          NaN        NaN
2          NaN        NaN
3       -0,00%   136376.0
4          NaN        NaN
5       -0,02%    50941.0
6       -0,04%   152213.0
7       -0,07%   146387.0
```

I would like to clean the `NaN` rows therefore I tried this:

```
return (route[1]).dropna(inplace=True)
```

It returns a `None`

The I tried to store `route[1]` in a variable and call it back like this:

```
tabla_rdos=route[1]
tabla_rdos=route[1].dropna(inplace=True)
```

Returning that :

```
 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dropna'
```

Then I checked:

```
return: tabla_rdos
```

returning `None`

I would simply like to return the table I obtained through the `read_html` without the NaN values. I don't understand why this struggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need remove `inplace=True`, becasue if `inplace=True` in pandas function it it always return `None`:

```
return (ruta[1]).dropna()
```